# Spring MVC CORS Mapping Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cors

Would anyone know a way to use systemProperties in the MVC CORS mapping?
I have a Spring MVC REST backend on Elastic Beanstalk and a Frontend on Cloudfront. I'd like to use Elastic Beanstalk configuration variables (passed as -DCORS_FRONTEND_URL = http://www.example.com), therefore I need systemProperties or equivalent.

What I have is:

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" allowed-methods="GET, PUT"
        max-age="3600" allowed-origins="http://www.example.com"/>
</mvc:cors>
```

What I want is:

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" allowed-methods="GET, PUT"
         max-age="3600" allowed-origins="#{systemProperties['CORS_FRONTEND_URL']}"/>
</mvc:cors>
```

Update:

So I editted the a [CorsBeanDefinitionParser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/ed6c5330797f790439db31cff95863a34533a0b6/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/CorsBeanDefinitionParser.java) class and printed out the `allowedOrigins` array.

It printed out `#{ systemProperties['cors.frontend.url'] }` whichs means the SpEL is not being evaluated in the application context as I had expected.

It looks like SpEL evaluation only works for manual bean definitions.

Update 2:
Java Context worked without issue.

```
/**
 * Spring Web MVC Java Context Configuration
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String corsFrontendUrl;

    @Autowired
    public WebMvcContext(@Nullable @Value("#{ systemProperties['cors.frontend.url'] }") String corsFrontendUrl){
        this.corsFrontendUrl = corsFrontendUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(@Nonnull CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(corsFrontendUrl)
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT")
            .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is supposed to work, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based. Do you see any error getting thrown with your current try?

Comment: Could you try with `systemEnvironment` instead of `systemProperties`?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work